# Anomalies beteen a char poiner and a integer pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

```
int *a;
*a=3;
cout<<a;
```

Why does the above code snippet shows the memory address while the code snippet below shows the whole string itself?

```
char *a;
a="string";
cout<<a;
```

How can I assign **"string"** directly to **a** while that was not possible in the case of int pointer?
Assigning **"string"** to pointer **a** should replace the address itself,right?
If that is not the case,then please elaborate what happens while compiling this code.

Comment: `*a=3` exhibits undefined behavior, by way of dereferencing an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: The second example calls `operator<<(const char*)` overload, which assumes its argument points to a C-style NUL-terminated string, and outputs the same. The first example calls `operator<<(void*)` overload, which outputs the address stored in the pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first example, `int *a;` creates a pointer to `int` with an undefined value, i.e. you didn't assign it to point anywhere.

The second line then places the value 3 in the random location pointed to by `a` which is likely to cause a program crash, but not always.

The third line prints the value of the pointer as a memory address.

In the second example, `char *a;` creates a pointer to `char` with a undefined value, i.e. you didn't assign it to point anywhere.

The second line then assigns `a` to point to the constant string `string`.

The third line print the string value of a because the std::stream class specialized the `<<` operator for `char*` to output the string.

Answer (score 0):

`std:ostream` specializes the `<<` operator based on the data type.  For `char*`, it assumes a string since that is the convention used in the C-language from which C++ evolved.  For other pointer types, operator `<<` just displays the pointer since there is no convention established to terminate non-char arrays (char array strings are terminated by a character value zero).

In the case of `a = "string"`, the address of `"string"` would be stored (although a good compiler would warn you about `const` issues).  This is a special case syntax applied only to arrays of characters -- again, because that was how the C-language managed text.

As an aside, this trend of providing special-case handling for `char` types has annoyed me many times over the years when I try to display an 8-bit integer but instead it shows me a character -- forcing me to cast.

```
uint8_t i=65;
cout<<"results: "<<i<<", "<<(int)i<<"\n";

results: A, 65
```